# How can i define a quantifier for a group of conditions in regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have this string :

```
"Za @Foo_Bar: @BAR_foo @FooBAR @BArfoo"
```

And a regex pattern like this:

```
((Za\s)?@[A-Za-z0-9_]*)|(@[A-Za-z0-9_]*)
```

or

```
(Za\s)?@[A-Za-z0-9_]*
```

I want it to return this list:

```
['Za @Foo_Bar','BAR_foo','FooBAR','BArfoo']
```

But I'm getting unexpected results:

```
>>> import re
>>> import regex
>>> a = "Za @Foo_Bar: @BAR_foo @FooBAR @BArfoo"
>>> regex.fullmatch(u'((Za\s)?@[A-Za-z0-9_]*)|(@[A-Za-z0-9_]*)',a) is None
True
>>> re.findall(u'((Za\s)?@[A-Za-z0-9_]*)|(@[A-Za-z0-9_]*)',a)
[('Za @Foo_Bar', 'Za ', ''), ('@BAR_foo', '', ''), ('@FooBAR', '', ''), ('@BArfoo', '', '')]
```

The second result is more convincing but it contains a lot of junk values:

```
>>> regex.findall(u'((Za\s)?@[A-Za-z0-9_]*)|(@[A-Za-z0-9_]*)',a)
[('Za @Foo_Bar', 'Za ', ''), ('@BAR_foo', '', ''), ('@FooBAR', '', ''), ('@BArfoo', '', '')]
>>> match  = re.search(u'((Za\s)?@[A-Za-z0-9_]*)|(@[A-Za-z0-9_]*)',a)
>>> match.groups()
('Za @Foo_Bar', 'Za ', None)
```

Why does `fullmatch` return `None`? How can I get a clean list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regex.fullmatch()` is the wrong method to use here, I don't think you understood what it is useful for.

From the [`regex` module documentation](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

> `fullmatch` behaves like `match`, except that it must match all of the string.

You pattern doesn't match *all* of the input string. Only if the pattern covers **everything**, from the first character to the last, will `fullmatch()` return a match.

Where `re.match()` only matches when at the start of the string, as if you added `\A` to the start of your pattern, `regex.fullmatch()` matches as if you added `\A` to the start, and `\Z` to the end of your pattern.

Note that you don't need the `|(@[A-Za-z0-9_]*)` option; that pattern is fully covered by the `(Za\s)?@[A-Za-z0-9_]*` part already, when `(Za\s)?` doesn't match.

To get a clean list, use `re.findall()` but use a `(?:...)` *non-capturing* group to cover the optional part ,so you don't get separate strings in the `re.findall()` result:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "Za @Foo_Bar: @BAR_foo @FooBAR @BArfoo"
>>> re.findall(r'(?:Za\s)?@[A-Za-z0-9_]*', a)
['Za @Foo_Bar', '@BAR_foo', '@FooBAR', '@BArfoo']
```

With no capturing groups, the whole match is returned.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you might use `(?<!\AZa):? @` and  split on an optional colon followed by a space and an `@` except for the first one in the string:

```
import re
s = "Za @Foo_Bar: @BAR_foo @FooBAR @BArfoo"
print(re.split('(?<!\AZa):? @', s))
```

Result

```
['Za @Foo_Bar', 'BAR_foo', 'FooBAR', 'BArfoo']
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rU1gvE/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tkBbut)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use groups:

```
import re

s = "Za @Foo_Bar: @BAR_foo @FooBAR @BArfoo"
g = re.findall(r'(?:Za\s)@\w+|(?<=@)\w+', s)
print(g)
```

**Output:**

```
['Za @Foo_Bar', 'BAR_foo', 'FooBAR', 'BArfoo']
```

**Explanation:**

```
  (?:Za\s)  # non capture group
  @         # @
  \w+       # 1 or more word character
|           #
  (?<=@)    # lookbehind, make sure we have @ before
  \w+       # 1 or more word character
```